# Ratio of real series and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, ratio

Assignment: Let $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k$ be series with positive, real entries. Suppose that the following limit exists:

$q=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{b_k}{a_k}$ with $0<q<\infty$.

I'm asked to prove that if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is convergent, then so is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k$, and vice versa for divergence.

Frankly, I'm at a loss here. I know that the limit $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k=a$ exists, and that the sequence $(a_k)^{\infty}_{k=1}$ must go to zero, but I haven't a clue how to proceed.

Any advice/pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want a proof of the Series Limit Comparison Test. Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: I think in some places you're confusing series and sequences. Especially here: "I know that the limit $\lim\limits{k\to\infty}a_k=a$ exists, and that the sequence $(a_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ must go to zero". Yes, both statements are true -- and moreover, it's the same statement, since it's the same sequence, so that limit is $a=0$.